# keras sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss function output shape didn't match

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I have a dataset which has 3570 labels. When I use the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function, the output shape didn't match.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, input_dim=79, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3570, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=10,
          batch_size=1,
          validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid))
```

and the output is 
`ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_42 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (1055, 3570)`

Then I fount this [issue#2444](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2444) and used `np.expand_dims(y, -1)` to change the code. But there was still have error.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, input_dim=79, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3570, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, np.expand_dims(y_train, -1),
          epochs=10,
          batch_size=1,
          validation_data=(x_valid, np.expand_dims(y_valid, -1)))
```

the error
`ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_45 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1055, 3570, 1)`

How should I change the code?

Answer (score 2):

`loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` is not meant for one-hot encodings but for integer targets. You probably need a "Dense(..."  as the output layer and use y_train directly.

Answer (score 1):

What are the original y_train dimensions?

Most likely is that your y_train has the shape (1055,). You need to One-Hot code y_train into a (1055,3570) dimension. Then the original code should work. Keras does not accept a single column of y using multiple classes, it has to be One-Hot coded.

You can find use the following:

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

y_cat = to_categorical(y, num_classes=None)
```

Comment: The original y_train dimensions are already (1055,3570) instead of (1055,).

Comment: Can you change the last layers activation function to "softmax" ?